# @charset utf-8 validation error in wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress, validation, charset

I'm trying to pass a wordpress site from https://validator.w3.org/ . I have fixed all errors apart from the "CSS: The @charset rule may only occur at the start of the style sheet. Please check that there are no spaces before it."

I have observed that there are 2 @charset utf-8 in the html of the site and think that the second @charset is the error the validator is complaining about. You may find the code below (the css of the second @charset)

```
@charset "UTF-8";.wp-block-separator{border-top:1px solid;border-bottom:1px solid}.wp-block-separator.is-style-wide{border-bottom-width:1px}.wp-block-separator.is-style-dots{background:none!important;border:none;text-align:center;line-height:1;height:auto}.wp-block-separator.is-style-dots:before{content:"···";color:currentColor;font-size:1.5em;letter-spacing:2em;padding-left:2em;font-family:serif}.wp-block-separator{border:none;border-bottom:2px solid;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;opacity:.4}.wp-block-separator:not(.is-style-wide):not(.is-style-dots){width:100px}.wp-block-separator.has-background:not(.is-style-dots){border-bottom:none;height:1px}.wp-block-separator.has-background:not(.is-style-wide):not(.is-style-dots){height:2px}↩
```

Additionally, I cannot locate where the relevant file is and how to correct it.
Thank you in advance, and sorry if not described well or missed information. More than happy to add more if needed.

Comment: There's not enough information here for someone to give a good answer. You can try disabling plugins one at a time and re-validate, to find which plugin is causing this problem for you. It is probable that a plugin is at fault here.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not a plugin because I have the exact same plugins working with no errors in another site. What other information could I add in order to help you understand the root cause?